# DBeaver will not allow me to join tables or run window functions

Tags: csv, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver PostgreSQL and I'm trying to join two CSV files but I get an error stating, "SQL Error: Syntax error: JOIN not supported". In addition, I am unable to run window functions.

SQL Error: Syntax error: JOIN not support[image]

SQL Window Function Error: [image]

Comment: Hello, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56321526/edit) your question to include the SQL as text. Text as images is not good. Some example data would be also nice since we don't have your CSV files

Comment: You are not using Postgres, you are using some kind of "CSV driver".

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver's CSV driver doesn't support joins. You should use 3rd party jdbc driver for this.

[Try this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/)

UPDATE:

The above driver doesn't work.
You should use CData driver, it has a trial version ([download](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/csv/jdbc/)).

[Here](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RVD/jdbc/pg_jdbcdbeaver.htm) is installation steps. 
This one definitely supports join, as it specified [here](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RVD/jdbc/pg_sfjoin.htm).

Comment: Hi, I tried downloading CsvJdbc and installing it but nothing happens. I tried Google and Youtube tutorials in regards of CsvJdbc but no avail. Do you happen to have any quick instruction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kayla yes, I just checked, it doesn't work with that driver. I've updated my answer. CData driver supports joins, but, probably, you should recreate the database.